# How to use <directory> directive within htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory

I have wrote this lines in my .htaccess file:

```
<Directory /img>
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</Directory>
```

But the server encountered an 500 Internal Server Error.
I really want to apply that rule to few directories (like: img/ js/ icons/ ),
but not to all of the image files in the site.

The question:
What is the right way to apply a rule to whole directory ?
Is it possible by single htacess file, without htacess file in each directory ?

Comment: Are you sure you want `<Directory /img>` and not `<Location /img>`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a `<Directory>` block inside an htaccess file (which is essentially a `<directory>` itself). If you want to have requests for `/img` set a cache-control header, then put:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
```

in the htaccess file in the `/img` directory.